# Is it possible to have a combination of whole and decimal numbers on the y axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, yaxis

Is it possible to remove the unnecessary decimal places which are being displayed using ggplot2? Below is the section of code that I am currently using. I need the exact breaks included as I have some very low values. I have also included a crude example of what is displayed in the figure which I generated for the purpose of this question so please ignore all other aspects of it!

```
scale_y_sqrt(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, ),
             breaks = c(0, 0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.25,
                        0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried to answer your question below, but I thought I should point out that something seems to be amiss with the errorbars in the plot image you have posted (there's also a typo on "nitrogen")

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the trailing decimals by manually specifying the labels for the axis points using the `labels` argument to `scale_y_sqrt()` or any other `scale_*_continuous()`

The code below should give you what you're looking for:

```
scale_y_sqrt(
  expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, ),
  breaks = c(
    0, 0.01, 0.025, 0.05, 0.1, 0.25,
    0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
  ),
  labels = c(
    "0", "0.01", "0.025", "0.05", "0.1", "0.25",
    "0.5", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
  ),
)
```

And here's a small reproducible example to illustrate the general point more completely:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = c(-2, -1, 0, .5, 1, 2),
    labels = c("-2", "-1", "0", "0.5", "1", "2")
  )
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Derek, you are a star. I can't believe I didn't consider such a simple solution!

Comment: Glad to help! If I've answered your question, please consider marking this as the accepted answer so others can see it clearly

Comment: I most certainly would, but I can't as I only have a 14 reputation. I do appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the breaks by not specifying them in the `breaks` argument of the function `scale_y_sqrt()` like:

```
scale_y_sqrt(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, ),
             breaks = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

By the way, you don't need to specify the break if you don't want precise breaks. `ggplot2` automatically computes what breaks to put depending on the range of your data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I require the exact breaks specified in my code so starting from 0.01. Including low values with decimal places in the code seems to cause the higher values to have decimal places too, and it looks messy. If I let ggplot compute my breaks, it misses all values between 0 and 1 which I need to display.